# NodeJS: aws-sdk sts.assumeRole is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, assume-role

I have a weird problem where I can't seem to go anywhere with. I have followed everything online (multiple tutorials etc) but can't get **sts.assumeRole** to work.

My set-up:

- Main AWS account (used for billing, IAM etc)
- Sub AWS account 1 (used
  for customer 1)
- Sub AWS account 2 (used for customer 2)
- etc

I have a bot running in **Sub AWS account 1** where I need pricing information from the **Main AWS account**.

So, I created a role on the **Main AWS account** to have AWS ce:* access, below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ce:*"],
            "Resource": ["*"]
        }]
}
```

**Trust Relationship**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::SubAWSaccount1-ID:role/instance-profile"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, this is the **instance-profile** attached to the EC2 instance running on the **Sub AWS account 1**:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::mainAWSaccount-ID:role/botRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Trust relationship**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
   {
    "Sid": "",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
   }
  ]
}
```

Okay, that being out of the way, this is the code that is not working:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var pricingAWS = new AWS.CostExplorer();

var getPricing = function(){

    var costParams = {
        TimePeriod: { Start: "2019-12-01 ", End: "2020-01-01"},
        Granularity: 'MONTHLY',
        Metrics: ['BlendedCost'],
        Filter: {      
            Dimensions: {
                Key: "LINKED_ACCOUNT",
                Values: ["Sub AWS account 2s ID"] //Main AWS account has access to many sub accounts info. So bot in running on Sub account 1, I need info from Sub account 1, 2, 3 etc and Role is on Main account
            }
        }
    };

    var roleToAssume = {
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::mainAWSaccount-ID:role/botRole',
        RoleSessionName: 'testTestTest',
        DurationSeconds: 900
    };

    var roleCreds = {};

    sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            roleCreds = {
                accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
            };

            pricingAWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: roleCreds.AccessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: roleCreds.SecretAccessKey,
                sessionToken: roleCreds.SessionToken
              });
        }
    });

    pricingAWS.getCostAndUsage(costParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }else{
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
};

getPricing();
```

What I get from the console.log(err)is:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::SubAWSAccount-1:assumed-role/slack-instance-profile/instanceID is not authorized to perform: ce:GetCostAndUsage on resource: arn:aws:ce:us-east-1:SubAWSAccount-1:/GetCostAndUsage'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to confirm my understanding, you are trying to assume a role in one account from an ec2 instance in another account.

1. create an IAM role in the `child` account
2. allow the newly created role above to assume the role exists in the `main` account by attaching an IAM policy. Allow the child role to assume the main role via the main role's trust policy (you are doing this already)
3. In your Nodejs code running in the child ec2 instance, assume the parent role and read the billing reports (you are already doing this)

#### code fixes

Move the `pricingAWS.getCostAndUsage()` line inside assume role callback. because the line is called before the credentials are updated :). You can also change everything to async/await as I showed below.

```
import AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var pricingAWS = new AWS.CostExplorer();
const sts = new AWS.STS()

var getPricing = async function () {

  var costParams = {
    TimePeriod: { Start: "2019-12-01 ", End: "2020-01-01" },
    Granularity: 'MONTHLY',
    Metrics: ['BlendedCost'],
    Filter: {
      Dimensions: {
        Key: "LINKED_ACCOUNT",
        Values: ["Sub AWS account 2s ID"] //Main AWS account has access to many sub accounts info. So bot in running on Sub account 1, I need info from Sub account 1, 2, 3 etc and Role is on Main account
      }
    }
  };

  var roleToAssume = {
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::mainAWSaccount-ID:role/botRole',
    RoleSessionName: 'testTestTest',
    DurationSeconds: 900
  };

  var roleCreds = {};


  try {

    const data = await sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume).promise();
    const roleCreds = {
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    };

    pricingAWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: roleCreds.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: roleCreds.secretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: roleCreds.sessionToken
    });

    const costAndUsage = await pricingAWS.getCostAndUsage(costParams).promise()
    return costAndUsage
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
    throw err;
  }

};

getPricing();
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't work. Actually IAM errors out as that role under that AWS account doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry I get the question now. I didn't realize that you are assigning the main account role to the ec2 instance profile directly. I will check and let you know/

Comment: Hey Arun. What you explained is exactly what I’m trying to do. I just don’t know how to do it, or why it’s failing when I feel I did everything right

Comment: apologies  again, can you get into the ec2 instance and then try to assume the role via command line.  `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::accountId:role/roleName --role-session-name "its-my-session"`

Comment: you can also run `aws sts get-caller-identity` command to see the role that the instance is assuming.

Comment: When I run this on the instance:
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::mainAccountID:role/roleName --role-session-name "botRole" - it works!

So I think this eliminates this being a infra set up issue. But my code looks perfect......

Comment: I have added what I got from console.log(err). I am very much lost in this one....

Comment: got the issue :) . the `pricingAWS.getCostAndUsage` is called before the credentials are updated. move that line inside the assume role callback, otherwise change the full code to async/await style

Comment: Also I have noticed, you are using `roleCreds.AccessKeyId`, but you are setting `roleCreds = { accessKeyId: 'value'}`. it should be lower case `access` not uppercase. good luck

Comment: That did it for me mate! I was so fixated on this being an issue with AWS' library or my usage of it that I ignored the basics. Thanks so much. Owe you a beer